# How can I improve the performance of my sub-query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I'm having problems with performance with IN queries in MYSQL.

Basically I'm building a friends graph , and when a user ~< 5 friends, it slows to crawl

however for users with high friends (7000+) - it runs super faster.

Here is my mock-up-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM activity
WHERE user_id IN 
(
   SELECT friend_id
   FROM friends
   WHERE user_id = 1 and approved = 1
)
order by activity.created_at DESC
LIMIT 25
```

For some reason if the user_id has < 5 friends, the query takes 15s to return 0 entries.

On the friends table, I have an index on user_id and approved. On the activity entry I have an index on created_at.

Any suggestions or re-factoring?

Comment: this is a sub-query -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimizing-subqueries.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically the subquery in your example will be executed per each row selected from `activity` table, you can reduce it by moving filter on `activity` table to the outer scope, so try to make your top-level query to be more specific in terms of filtering.

Try out `INNER JOIN`, does it work faster?

```
SELECT * FROM activity a
INNER JOIN friends f ON a.user_id = f.friend_id
WHERE a.user_id = 1 AND f.approved = 1
order by activity.created_at DESC LIMIT 25
```

Few questions:

- Both tables has a user_id column?
- approved column in the friends table?

Comment: It should be `... WHERE f.user_id = 1 ...` or not? +1 though
The query should pull last 25 activities of your friends, I think.

Comment: Both tables have the user_Id and approved is in the friends table.

Comment: Running the query above (with f.user_id) = is 6s. Explain shows friends being the first table and activity second and - Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Answer (score 0):

Would this

`SELECT *
FROM activity t1 join friends t2 where t1.user_id=t2.friends_id and t2.user_id=1 and t2.approved=1 order by activity.created_at DESC
LIMIT 25`

accomplish the same. And is it any quicker?

I think you will need an index on friend_id,user_id, approved for the friends table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
FROM activity a
JOIN (Select * from friends WHERE user_id = 1 and approved = 1) f
ON a.user_id = f.friend_id
ORDER BY a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Basically, IN's are kind of unpredictable, I like to use JOINs whenever possible.

Comment: This works for the small users, but with high friends (> 7000) its slow. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* FROM activity a, friends f
WHERE 
           a.user_id = f.friend_id
    AND    f.user_id = 1 
    AND    f.approved = 1
ORDER BY activity.created_at DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Have an index on each: `a.user_id`, `f.friend_id` and `f.user_id`.

Do NOT index `f.approved` since it is very likely low cardinality column.